# Debugging Memory Leak on C/C++ Application running on Embedded Linux Device

Tags: c++, linux

I have an application running on an ARM Cortex-A9.  When I enter a certain portion of the code, I can see in the Linux tasks view 'top' that the application grows in memory usage until it gets Killed due to running out of physical memory.

Now, I have done some research on this and tried to implement mtrace, but it didn't give me very concise results.  Basically I get something like this

```
Memory not freed:
-----------------
   Address     Size     Caller
0x03aafe18     0x38  at 0x76e73c18
0x53a004a8     0x38  at 0x76e73c18
```

And I do not even think this is the big problem (maybe another smaller issue).

I also cannot use Valgrind (which would probably work great) because there is not enough space on the device to install it and a compiler...

So I fear that I just have to go through the code and look for something that could be causing growing memory usage.  Is there a guide for this somewhere?  In the code, "malloc" or "new" is almost never used.

I do have access to use gdb, if that can help.

One thing I am not clear on is if the following is a problem:

```
while(someloop){
...
   double *someptr;
...
}
```

or like

```
while(someloop){
...
   int32 someArray[100] = {0};
...
}
```

Of which there is a lot of in the code.  When that loop comes around, and instantiates those variables or pointers, does it just keep using free space, or use the spaces from the last iteration?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the shown code. The bug must be elsewhere.

Comment: Why do you need a compiler on the device?!

Comment: In response to the last two snippets: the code should be using the space from the last iteration. If it was allocating more space each time, it would overflow the stack (since those variables are allocated on the stack). Note that you can look at the assembly code to confirm this. Compile with `-S` to get the assembly code, or look at the assembly code with the debugger.

Comment: post the `malloc`s and `new`s

Comment: If `malloc` and `new` (why use both?) are almost never used, that should simplify the task of finding the leak.

Comment: Are you using malloc in your first example without freeding that memory before while ends?

Comment: @n.m. I'd need the compiler on the device to install Valgrind, no?  Let me know if there is another way.

Comment: valgrind on the device, maybe. Compiler shouldn't be needed. Also consider abstracting away your hardware-specific functionality from the main program logic. That way you can test and debug most functionality on PC hardware where the tools are generally much easier to wrangle.

Comment: No, you need to compile for the device on a regular computer using a cross compiler.

Comment: There is no language C/C++, but the two **different** languages C and C++. Remove the unrelated tag!

Comment: Do you have recursive calls? multiple static allocations may push you out of stack memory.

Answer (score 1):

If it is alocated on the stack, the memory is reused. However by alocating on heap you need to delete.
Also if you alocate with double * ptr; ... ptr = new double [5], you need to delete by delete [] ptr.

In C++ you can overwrite the new and delete operators to print some message for debuging.

Best would be to debug using gdb and see what object is created and not deleted.

It is possible that you use a class in your code that does not delete something internal.

Tip: for small objects alocating on stack is both faster and safer.